# ReactNative 0.71.13 production release asks metro to be running

Tags: react-native, react-native-upgrade

We have updated our React Native app from  0.67.5 to 0.71.13 in development build everything works perfectly on both iOS and Android. But when I'm trying to make production (release) build, on iOS it works, I tried pushing to appStoreConnect and install it via test flight. But on Android it's a whole different story. I've tried pushing release build to internal testing lane and install it on my device. Install succeeds, but when I'm trying to start app it crashed and I get this error in analytics:

`Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'app.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.`

I've tried googling a lot, found [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/53f55001afbf07494de0df064a92dfdd42f37c98). As I understand this bug was resolved when using gradle plugin 4.1.0+/gradle 6.5 I've tried using multiple different combinations, but I've always getting same error.

Maybe someone has been in a same situation and can help me?

Comment: How do you build the release apk?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to get it working on emulator building with
`npm run android -- --mode="release"`

I've also tried building it with Android Studio via GUI (Generate Signed Bundle / APK).

Also I've trying using Fastlane as we used it to deploy our builds before update.

Comment: Have you uninstall any previous version of the app yet?

Comment: Yes, before each `npm run` I remove previous app in emulator.